# Fixing texture with JPEG artifacts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg, visual-artifacts

I have this texture:
[image]

That I really want to use. The problem is when I zoom in to it, it is full of JPEG artifacts and does not scale nicely. I tried a few noise reducing plug ins but they did not give a very nice result.

Is there a way to either make an image very similar to this in Photoshop, or not really get rid of the artifacts?

Thanks

Comment: I just tested this on a blank HTML page. If there are any visual problems, they are very subtle. It looks good over here, **15.6 in, 1366 x 768**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a graphics wizard at all, but this image looks fine to me... When you zoom it, you see JPG artifacts AND you notice the lack of data to zoom while keeping the image sharpness. You might want to apply a filter on it to lightly blur it as to attenuate the JPG artifacts, but you can't invent image data while zooming. It WILL get ugly. I'm not sure I'm getting your exact problem. I feel like saying the obvious, but yeah, you can just zoom so much as you have acquisition data on an image. If you can find the original and compress it in a loss-less way (or less lossy at least), that will help you zoom a bit further.